# AWK for-loop with break statment

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, awk, break

Today I am working on a problem correcting data errors in files that have a few unknowns.  The unknowns are the number of fields in each file, and which fields and records have the string "---".

An example of the data is:

```
1  2  1    39.6406  1    38.8512  1    38.3479  1    37.9744
2  1  4    39.1527  3    38.7329  2    38.3479  2    37.9744
3  3  3    39.5186  2    38.8512  3    38.2079  3    37.6385
4  4  2    39.6406  4    38.4964  ---  37.7414  ---  36.7149
5  5  ---  40.2504  ---  39.0286  ---  38.4879  ---  38.1004
```

The desired output is:

```
1  2  1    39.6406  1    38.8512  1    38.3479  1    37.9744
2  1  4    39.1527  3    38.7329  2    38.3479  2    37.9744
3  3  3    39.5186  2    38.8512  3    38.2079  3    37.6385
4  4  2    39.6406  4    38.4964  ---  ---      ---  ---
5  5  ---  ---      ---  ---      ---  ---      ---  ---
```

I have tried using for-loops, such as:

```
awk '{for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--){if ($i=="---")$(i-1)="---"}{print $0}}' file
```

which resulted in:

```
1    2  1  39.6406  1  38.8512  1  38.3479  1  37.9744
2    1  4  39.1527  3  38.7329  2  38.3479  2  37.9744
3    3  3  39.5186  2  38.8512  3  38.2079  3  37.6385
---
---
```

and I also tried:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i=="---")$(i+1)="---"}{print $0}}' file
```

which resulted in the error:

```
"awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767"
    FILENAME="file" FNR=4 NR=4
1  2  1  39.6406  1  38.8512  1  38.3479  1  37.9744
2  1  4  39.1527  3  38.7329  2  38.3479  2  37.9744
3  3  3  39.5186  2  38.8512  3  38.2079  3  37.6385
```

In my first attempt, the for-loop went all the way to the first field, and in the second attempt, the records with the desired string had an infinite loop.

My gut feeling is I need to apply a break statement, yet after many hours of searching, I can't find an example that has helped me.  I know there is more then one way to skin a cat, so if you know a better way to accomplish my goal, keeping in mind that there are multiple files with different field counts, or if you can provide an example of a break statement with one of my for-loops, I, and others looking for an example, will be extremely grateful.

Thank you

Comment: one issue I see is you're not incrementing/decrementing the index by two and overlapping ranges in each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<NF;i+=2) if($i=="---") $(i+1)=$i}1' file | 
  column -t

1  2  1    39.6406  1    38.8512  1    38.3479  1    37.9744
2  1  4    39.1527  3    38.7329  2    38.3479  2    37.9744
3  3  3    39.5186  2    38.8512  3    38.2079  3    37.6385
4  4  2    39.6406  4    38.4964  ---  ---      ---  ---
5  5  ---  ---      ---  ---      ---  ---      ---  ---
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to add that to my grimoire  :-)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a simple substitution so that's an ideal job for sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(-+ +)[^ ]+/\1\1  /g' file
1  2  1    39.6406  1    38.8512  1    38.3479  1    37.9744
2  1  4    39.1527  3    38.7329  2    38.3479  2    37.9744
3  3  3    39.5186  2    38.8512  3    38.2079  3    37.6385
4  4  2    39.6406  4    38.4964  ---  ---      ---  ---
5  5  ---  ---      ---  ---      ---  ---      ---  ---
```